# UITextView showing text in Modal View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, modalviewcontroller

How can I show new text in UITextView in modal?
So, here is the text, and I have 2 views, main and modal. I need to display text, which was set in main view, in modal. The TextView in modal was created.

```
textView.text = @"test";
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

It's not an idea, cause it don't display text in modal :(

Comment: Have you tried changing the `frame` property of the text view to take up the entire view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would have a uiviewcontroller subclass with the text view in it, the present that vc modally. Then the initial text string is a property of that vc. If this does not work for you, write a small demo app and post it to DropBox.

Comment: Forgot about specify class for controller. :)